# How to manage code of UWP in different platform?

Tags: uwp

guys.I am writing a programme of UWP.It will running in WINDOWS 10(X86 Platform) and WINDOWS IOT(ARM Platform)
Two different platform almost 90% codes are the same,and 10% is different.
I don't want to create two different project,it will make me write many codes twice.It's unnecessary.
However,I wanna that if the Visual Studio has a way to let me solve this.For example:if running in ARM,it won't compile the code of X86;if running in X86,it won't compile the code of ARM.
Can Visual Studio do this?Or how can I solve it?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Package package = Package.Current;
var os = package.Id.Architecture.ToString();

if (os == "X86")
{
 //Write code works in X86 only
}
else if (os == "X64")
{
 //Write code works in X64 only
}
else 
{
 //Write code works in ARM only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not a question.
UWP app can run on x86,x64 and arm architectures.Because only when you build you code,you should choose build to x86,x64 and arm,not at runtime,that's impossible.

when you write your logic code,you almost don't need  to care about which architecture your app will be running.

I think what you should care about points are:

- Dirffrent UI layout and interaction,you can use adaptive,responsible design which Microsoft adviced.
- Platform specific.Iot device have some features which Desktop doesn't have  and vice versa.
  you can use Windows Iot Extentions for UWP and Windows Desktop Extentions for uwp to implement those platform specific function.